# HTML checkbox won't display correctly with javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Shouldn't this javascript just display an unchecked checkbox followed by the text "MyCheckBox"? Instead, it's just displaying "checked."

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var data = false;
    document.write('<input type="checkbox" ' + data ? "checked" : "" + '>MyCheckBox');
</script>
</head>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `head` element is not purposed to render any HTML. Also the ternary should be wrapped in the parentheses within a string concatenation.

Comment: You're missing parentheses

Comment: `document.write('<input type="checkbox" ' + (data ? "checked" : "") + '>MyCheckBox');` just added parantheses

Comment: See [`<head>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head), only metadata content permitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the correction:

```
document.write('<input type="checkbox" ' + (data ? "checked" : "") + '>MyCheckBox');
```

You were missing the parentheses.

Also, don't put that inside `<head>`, like Teemu said, you can't render HTML there.

Comment: Outstanding! I had no idea I had to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just Do This.

```js
var data=false,
a=document.createElement("input");
a.setAttribute("type","checkbox");
a.checked=data;
document.body.append(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even when you can have the desired result with this line:

`document.write("<input type='checkbox' " + (data ? "checked" : "") + ">MyCheckBox");`

It is not the best way, you are writing to a stream and that is a risky business. Handling in the structured way, you can do it in this way:

```
`var data = false;
var check=document.createElement("input");
check.id="mycheckbox"
check.type="checkbox";
check.checked=data;
document.body.appendChild(check)`
```